# Remerge MR in GitLab

Tags: git, gitlab, git-merge

I did a Merge Request and already merged it, but want to edit commit messages squash/unsquash commits, etc. I know that I can do something that via `git commit --fixup`/`git rebase` into merged branch, but what will be with the MR itself? Will it be automatically fixed or not?

Let's say I have a source branch:

```
$ git log --oneline -n2
b6ddddddd commit message 1
b7ddddddd commit message 2
```

And I have a branch where source branch is merged to:

```
$ git log --oneline -n2
c6cccccac Merge branch `source` into `destination`
c7cccccbc MR Commit message
```

Here I have MR that actually has two squashed commits (`b6ddddddd`, `b7ddddddd`), but I want to "unsquash" commits and redo MR (that one is merged), is there a way to do so or I need to open a new MR?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I did a Merge Request and already merged it

That would mean "reopening the MR", and that is not currently (2022) possible, as [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52126860/6309).

It is best to make a new separate MR, with the source branch rebased on top the target remote branch, and where you can push again, for said new MR.